# 6 pin 3 state slide switch

Tags: switches

Is there a standard way in which 3 state, 6 pin slide switches are connected? I haven't been able to find any schematic online.

Originally, I assumed that each pair of pins corresponds to the in/out ports of each of the switch's three states. Having the switch in one of these three states would then close the circuit between the two corresponding pins. However, I have discovered that this is not the case.

I can attach a picture of my switch, but I don't have a model number so I don't know if it would be of much use.

Comment: It may be a DPDT, center-off switch. Do you have an ohmmeter or any other sort of continuity checker?

Comment: You have a switch without a model number and you have discovered that it isn't wired how you originally believed but haven't told how it is wired or what it looks like. Looks like you hold all the aces still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical configuration very close to Dave Tweed answer (DPDT) except that if I understand your question properly, then your switch handle has 3 positions and not 2 (DPDT)
My guess is that the two middle pins are the Common pins. Sliding the handle to the right for example, would connect each common pin to its respective end pin on the right.
If I am correct then your 3 position switch should show no connections between any of the 6 pins at all when the slide is in the middle. Easily checked with a ohmmeter 
BTW I never saw a switch behave as per your assumption

Comment: Many things get assumed!! Usually from lack of effort to research the facts or investigate the true nature of things. Sometimes it is sheer desire for something to be one way that reality is simply overlooked.

Comment: I took your advice and used an ohmmeter to check for continuity. It happens that the functionality I need can be achieve using only 3 of the 6 pins. The middle pin serves as the common pin for the pins to its left and right. The three states ON-OFF-OFF, shorts the middle & left, nothing, and middle & right pins respectively. Same this goes for both sides.

Thanks!